# jQuery validator assistance: How can I use a "submit" hyperlink instead of a "submit" button and have jQuery validator validate?

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have to use a hyperlink instead of a input submit or input button to submit a form. It needs to be validated by jQuery validator. When I use the input submit or input button, everything works perfectly, however a hyperlink doesn't validate at all when I put a submit() in the href (the form submits but no validation takes place). How can I run the validator plugin from a hyperlink then submit the form...? Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing in the world:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e) { 
  /* do the validation */
  if (validationFailed) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});

$("#mylink").click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); /* because you don't want to GO anywhere */
  $("#myform").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an a tag and add an onclick event to a tag and do the validation in the click event.

```
<a onclick="ValidateForm()">Submit</a>


Javascript:

function ValidateForm()
{
   $("#myForm").validate();
}
```